# How to replace a regex with parentheses keeping the parentheses c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to do some regex replace on files and the strings that I'm trying to replace contains things like `()[]{}`...etc and I want to keep as it after the replace, here is a simple example

```
string str = @"This is a drill (2).";
string reseult = Regex.Replace(str, "\\((\\d+)\\)", "\\(<x>$1</x>\\)");

Console.WriteLine(reseult);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The result should output `This is a drill (<x>2</x>).` but it is outputting `This is a drill \(<x>2</x>\).` Same goes for `[]`

Why is this happening and how to solve this without using the verbatim alternative?

Comment: Judicious use of `Regex.Escape` should prevent you from going insane with multiple layers of escaping.

Comment: Using a verbatim string (prefixed with `@`) for regex pattern strings makes things much simpler.

Comment: Remove escapes in replacement string. This is not regex.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(str, "\\((\\d+)\\)", "(<x>$1</x>)");`? You don't need to escape the parantheses in the replacement value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = @"This is a drill (2).";
string reseult = Regex.Replace(str, "\\((\\d+)\\)", "(<x>$1</x>)");

Console.WriteLine(reseult);
Console.ReadLine();
```

You don't need to escape parentheses in the final part. It is not regex. Similarly for other braces you dont need to escape them either. Just use this.

```
string str = @"This is a drill (2).";
string reseult = Regex.Replace(str, "\\((\\d+)\\)", "{<x>$1</x>}");

Console.WriteLine(reseult);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what about `", $,^,#,+, ?, |` ? do I need to keep them as they are in a replace?

Comment: @Don_B Yes. The replace need not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = @"This is a drill (2).";
string reseult = Regex.Replace(str, "\\((\\d+)\\)", "(<x>$1</x>)");

Console.WriteLine(reseult);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: thanks...but does it apply for all things that needs escaping in the search pattern